# Gravity forms update custom filed in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

I am using gravity forms and having a hard time understanding how to update a already created custom post. Looking for direction.

Custom post type 
name: players 
value: sp_player

Custom field
A checkbox from a 3rd party plugin called sportspress located on the player profile post

name: season
Value: sp_players [0] [6]

Here is what is happening:
When player is created it adds them to a taxonomy of league and allows for stats to be added on their player post. Now in the admin area of that custom post  it adds a custom area where there is a unchecked checkbox.

Here is what I need to happen:
I need to check that box upon update and then save post. Not sure how to do. Any help is appreciated. Below is the direction I think I need to move but cannot figure it out

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {

//getting post
$post = get_post( $entry['post_id'] );

//changing post content
$post->post_content = 'Blender Version:' . rgar( $entry, '7' ) . "<br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '8' ) . "'> <br/> <br/> " . rgar( $entry, '13' ) . " <br/> <img src='" . rgar( $entry, '5' ) . "'>";

//updating post
wp_update_post( $post );
```

}